# Violación de segmento (`core' generado) en Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema, hace mucho tiempo que intento utilizar Spyder y no ingresa, cuando escribo "Spyder" en la terminal de Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, aparece el cuadro verde de Spyder cargando, cuando ya acaba, no aparece nada y en la terminal recibo el mensaje "Violación de segmento (`core' generado)".

Alguien sabe cómo se soluciona? Ya he desinstalado Anaconda y he vuelto a instalarlo y me sigue sucediendo, en Jupyter Notebook no tengo problemas solo en Spyder, me pasa lo mismo si ingreso desde anaconda-navigator hacia Spyder, recibo "/home/MiUsuario/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/spyder.sh: línea 3:  7366 Violación de segmento  (`core' generado) spyder"

Tengo la versión 3.3.8 de Spyder.

Comment: Hola thrashrider, en  https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6968. se expone un bug similar, en teoría está corregido para Spyder >= 3.3.X ¿Estás seguro de tener instalada esa versión de spyder?, [La última versión es la 3.3.1](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/tag/v3.3.1)?

Comment: Tenés razón, puse un 3 de más, es la 3.2.8, justo estoy actualizando a la 3.3.1, si no se corrige con eso probaré el link que me pusiste, muchas gracias FJSevilla.